# plot error in matlab Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket

Tags: matlab, parentheses

I want plot this function in Matlab:

```
F(p)=((3/2)*(7.02^2))-(2*18*p((1-(p/18))*(1-(exp(-18/p))))
```

I tried to make the plot as described in [this](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-27853.html) Mathworks page. And I wrote this :

```
p=0.001:0.001:10;
F=(((3/2)*(7.02^2))-(2*18*p((1-(p/18))*(1-(exp(-18/p)))));
plot(p,y)
```

but I got an error:

```
??? F=(((3/2)*(7.02^2))-(2*18*p((1-(p/18))*(1-(exp(-18/p)))));
                                                            |
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

I tried also to some loop like this:

```
p=0.01:0.01:10;
F=zeros(1,length(p))
for i = 1:1000
F(i)=(((3/2)*(7.02^2))-(2*18*p(i)((1-(p(i)/18))*(1-(exp(-18/p(i))))));
end
plot(p,y)
```

but I got the error :

```
??? F=(((3/2)*(7.02^2))-(2*18*p((1-(p/18))*(1-(exp(-18/p)))));
                                                            |
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

??? Error: File: Untitled2.m Line: 4 Column: 70
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

I don't understand where the problem is...

Comment: write the calculation using temp variables over several lines

Answer (score 1):

You clearly have either too many `(` or too many `)`. Count them, and use the Matlab editor's syntax highlighting and help to find where exactly.

Comment: ok .. you are right 

I I tried this script and i t worked :

    p=0.01:0.01:10;
    F=zeros(1,length(p))
    for i = 1:1000;
    F(i)=((3/2)*(7.02^2))-(2*18*p(i)*((1-(p(i)/18))*(1-(exp(-18/p(i))))));
    end
    plot(p,F)

but I tried this on and it didn't work 

    p=0.01:0.01:10;
    
    F=((3/2)*(7.02^2))-(2*18*p*((1-(p/18))*(1-(exp(-18/p)))));
    
    plot(p,F)

it returns an error
??? Error using ==> mldivide
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: use `./` instead of `/` for element-by-element division instead of matrix division

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues here.  The first is the number of `(` and `)` that you are using.  The second is that you aren't accounting for the fact that `p` is a vector and that requires `.*` and `./` operators since matrix operations aren't always as simple as saying `A times B` when the vector lengths don't match.

Either way, this should work for you now...

`F=(((3/2)*(7.02^2))-(2*18*p.*(1-(p./18))).*(1-(exp(-18./p))));`

In the future it helps to just simple count the number of `(` and `)` like @rubenvb mentioned.  That will give you a great indicator of where the issue might be.

In this particular case you would have gotten the matrix dimension mismatch error due to what I stated about the multiplication and division above.

Hope that helps.